# Express a 90 degree rotation matrix in terms of a 180 degree rotation matrix? (both anti-clockwise)

Tags: matrices, transformation, rotations

A = 
[-1  0  0 ]
[ 0-1  0 ]
[ 0  0  1 ]

B = 
[0 -1  0 ]
[ 1 0  0 ]
[ 0  0  1 ]

How can i represent B in terms of A?

Comment: Hint: there are two row operations, one switching rows 1 and 2, and another negating one of the rows.

Comment: @peterwhy That would not really be totally "in terms of $A$", but I concede it's possible that maybe that is what the OP is looking for. I guess we'll find out.

Comment: I guess transposition and inversion don't even matter considering what $A$ is...

Comment: @rschwieb And then these row operations translate to matrix multiplications.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, matrix multiplications in which $B$ is expressed in terms of $A$ *and* something else. And that could be perfectly fine.

Comment: @ash Can you be more specific about what can appear in the right hand side of $B=\_\_$? Beyond the obvious relationship $B^2=A$, it's hard to see other relationships between them...

Comment: @ash I can as well say $B = A + \pmatrix{1&-1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&0}$, which is likely not what you wanted. So please be specific.

Comment: My tutor actually told me that the answer is A^3 but doesn't that just gives you A again? This is why I'm asking here. Maybe my tutor gave us a dodgy question.